# How to cross compile for arm video for linux and udev

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, video4linux

I am trying to make our application work on an Arm device, specs:

```
Architecture:          aarch64
Byte Order:            Little Endian
Model name:            ARMv8 Processor rev 3 (v8l)
```

and for this I have installed the necessary cross compiler

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu g++-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

and since we use Qt, I also cross compiled Qt for this specific architecture:

```
./configure -xplatform linux-aarch64-gnu-g++ -opensource \
  -confirm-license -nomake tests -nomake examples -static \
  -skip qtwebengine -release -prefix /opt/qt5-arm -no-xcb \
  -no-opengl -no-use-gold-linker
```

Our application links with video for linux so we have the following compile line:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++  -o bin/executable <removed unimportant stuff>... 
   -lv4l2 -lv4lconvert -L/opt/qt5-arm/plugins/imageformats -lqgif 
   -L/opt/qt5-arm/lib -lqicns -lqico -lqjpeg -lQt5DBus 
   -lQt5Gui -lqtlibpng -lqtharfbuzz -lQt5Network -lQt5Core 
   -lm -lqtpcre2 -ldl -lpthread
```

And since I did not cross compile video for linux obviously I have got the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lv4l2
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lv4lconvert
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and here comes the question:

From where do I get the sources for video4linux, and how do I cross compile them for my architecture? Please note, I have found something which is named v4l-utils from https://www.linuxtv.org/downloads/ but:

1. it requires to link with libudev (which is not present in the cross compiled libraries' directory and I have no idea from where to get it)
2. I don't think it's what I require :)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Perhaps you can try to install the libudev package in your host machine?  # `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev libsystemd-dev`

Answer (score 0):

`ld` is not able to find the v4l package, you need to install the package in your build system or download the package manually and provide the path.

```
sudo apt install v4l-utils
```

After installing the package if you type command `which v4l2` it will provide the path where it's installed from that you will know you have the library that is needed.

You can download the package from this site as well. https://packages.debian.org/sid/v4l-utils

---

Source code for the v4l2 its part of the linux kernel driver [v4l2](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/media/v4l2-core)